# jqlite change event does not works as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have created a directive to validate my data from server

in the link function of my directive i catch hold of the element and attach a change event to it as fallows
  return function (scope, element) {

```
    element.bind("change", function () {
      //  element.attr('readonly',true);
       //console.log(element.val());
        var promise = orderData.vaidateBP(element.val());

       // console.log(promise);

        promise.then(
            function (data) {
                console.log(data.value);
                element.attr('readonly',false);
                scope.SoHeader.soldBP=data.value},
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }


            );
        //console.log(scope.SoHeader.soldBP);

    })
}
```

i call a service method vaidateBP on orderData which makes a restful call to the server
but what i found is the ajax call is made only every second time i.e
suppose the text box is black at first i change its value to "test" and tab
the ajax call is not made,but if i focus on the text box and try typing any thing at the first character entered in it fires the ajax call and so on ,thus the ajax call is fired only every second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution,
putting the call back event inside scope.$apply does the trick!